# Captuar propriedades de um botao adiciondo dinamicamente Kivy

Tags: python, python-kivy

Estou com um problema, tenho um app criado em Python e Kivy que possui uma tela que assim que é acessada cria alguns botôes de forma dinâmica. Gostaria de saber como capturar o texto do botão que foi clicado.

Python:

```
def on_enter(self):
    lista_series =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    for i in lista_series:
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
```

Ao clicar qualquer botão, gostaria do retorno do texto do botão clicado.